# Scala Regex: splitting by , while ignoring nested square brackets fails

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I am trying to parse a text using regex on the below text:

sample text:

```
{"entities":["Amphibians","Anura"],"journalVolume":"33","journalPages":"446-451","pmid":"","year":2004,"outCitations":[],"s2Url":"https://semanticscholar.org/paper/7e58b926bbbc122edeccb7cb4f7f68ca11480698","s2PdfUrl":"","id":"7e58b92","authors":[{"name":"M. V. Ushakov","ids":["2506899"]}],"journalName":"Russian Journal of Ecology","paperAbstract":"The marsh frog, is a widespread(Vykhodtseva, 1992; Vykhodtseva and Klimov, 1993; Kovylina and Vykhodtseva, 1993; Klimov et al. , 1999)","inCitations":[],"pdfUrls":[],"title":"Ecomorphological","doi":"10.1023/A:1020916001559","sources":[],"doiUrl":"https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1020916001559","venue":"Russian Journal"}
```

I am trying to parse it to get output as below:

Expected Output:

```
{"entities":["Amphibians","Anura"]
"journalVolume":"33"
"journalPages":"446-451"
"pmid":""
"year":2004
"outCitations":[]
"s2Url":"https://semanticscholar.org/paper/7e58b926bbbc122edeccb7cb4f7f68ca11480698"
"s2PdfUrl":""
"id":"7e58b92"
"authors":[{"name":"M. V. Ushakov","ids":["2506899"]}]
"journalName":"Russian Journal of Ecology"
"paperAbstract":"The marsh frog, is a widespread(Vykhodtseva, 1992; Vykhodtseva and Klimov, 1993; 
Kovylina and Vykhodtseva, 1993; Klimov et al. , 1999)"
"inCitations":[]
"pdfUrls":[]
"title":"Ecomorphological"
"doi":"10.1023/A:1020916001559"
"sources":[]
"doiUrl":"https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1020916001559"
"venue":"Russian Journal"}
```

However, I get an issue where I have open square parenthesis([) nested inside ([) as in the authors token below. I want to skip that. I have used the below regex:

Reg exp used:

```
",(?![^\\[]*[\\]])(?=(?:([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$))"
```

CurrentOutput:

```
{"entities":["Amphibians","Anura"]
"journalVolume":"33"
"journalPages":"446-451"
"pmid":""
"year":2004
"outCitations":[]
"s2Url":"https://semanticscholar.org/paper/7e58b926bbbc122edeccb7cb4f7f68ca11480698"
"s2PdfUrl":""
"id":"7e58b92"
**"authors":[{"name":"M. V. Ushakov"
"ids":["2506899"]}]**
"journalName":"Russian Journal of Ecology"
"paperAbstract":"The marsh frog, is a widespread(Vykhodtseva, 1992; Vykhodtseva and Klimov, 1993;     
Kovylina and Vykhodtseva, 1993; Klimov et al. , 1999)"
"inCitations":[]
"pdfUrls":[]
"title":"Ecomorphological"`enter code here`
"doi":"10.1023/A:1020916001559"
"sources":[]
"doiUrl":"https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1020916001559"
"venue":"Russian Journal"}
```

Is it doable using regex or is there any other way in scala like parser combinators?

Comment: You should not parse JSON with regex. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: Is lift-json the best way?

Comment: Any JSON parser you can use is good unless the JSON is corrupt and you need to create a workaround.